# Fitting of a non-scalar function

Tags: python, statistics, curve-fitting

I need your help.

Let us assume I have datasets y1(x),...,yn(x) with a variable x. How can I fit the models to a non scalar function?
[image: example]
In this example you see how I fitted with the least-squares method each dataset. The problem is that now all the shared paramters differ, and the fit was not optimized with respect to shared parameters.

Comment: I assume that you mean x is a 4-dimensional vector instead of a single value. If so, then you can still use least squares. Your sum of squared errors to minimize is just the sum of the squared errors for each of the 4 components.

Comment: x is one dimensional, thats the clue. F: R -> R^n

Comment: Sorry, I meant y of course.

Comment: Robert, do you have examples or an theoretic approach why I can still use the sum of the squared errors? Since they are connected via the direct product I was quite unsure about this.

Comment: I would say it depends on the result you want to obtain. Following Robert's suggestion, you will obtain the minimum error with respect to each dimension. Actually, this method does not care at all about the multi-dimensionality. You may also be interested in minimising the orthogonal distance to your model. That can be handled by orthogonal distance regression. In conclusion, it depends on what you actually want.

Comment: @varantir Write SSE = sum(||yhat_i - y_i||^2, i, 1, n), i.e., SSE = sum of squared distances from yhat to y. That's the ordinary SSE in 1 dimension and sum(sum((yhat_ij - y_ij)^2, j, 1, m), i, 1, n) where m = number of dimensions of y in 2 or more dimensions.